# SQL server profiler in the background with data saved to table

Tags: sql, iis, profiler

I want to run sql server profiler in the background. I know you can use SQL Trace but I want the trace info saved in a table and not in a file, and as far as I know you can only save to a file using SQL Trace.

What I am trying to do is leave sql trace running in the background and whenever an asp page  generates a 500 error I send an email to the admin. Among the IIS related info in the email,  I also want to include the last 50 lines from the trace. That is why I need the info in a table, so I can easily send it in the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Profiler (in 2005 / 2008) to save the results to a table by selecting the `Save to table` checkbox when creating the trace.

Note: Before proceeding you should read [this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2008/08/06/SQL-Profiler-best-practices.aspx)